stale github actions not automatically deleting prs
I want to automatically delete prs that have been opened and have no activity in x number of time. I created a github action workflow and merged it to my main, and then created two test prs to see if the github action worked to delete them automatically.
It has been 5 days and it still didnt work. I'm not sure what the problem is. Below is the code I used, in the folder repo_name/.gitub/workflows/stale.yml
name: Stale PRs

on:
  schedule:
    # Run this action every day at midnight
    - cron: '0 0 * * *'  # This will trigger the workflow daily at midnight UTC
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]  # Trigger on PR events

jobs:
  stale:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Mark stale pull requests
        uses: actions/stale@v5
        with:
          # Set the number of days after which a PR becomes stale
          stale-duration: 2 # PRs that haven't had activity in x days will be marked as stale
          # Days after being marked stale to close the PR
          close-duration: 2 # PRs that are stale for x days will be closed automatically
          repo-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}


Try the latest version i.e. v9 instead of v5 of https://github.com/actions/stale. May need to set the permissions. See https://github.com/actions/stale?tab=readme-ov-file#recommended-permissions.
